# Where can I play chess online without extra rules?

Tags: lichess, chess.com

I tried both chess.com and lichess but both have their own made up rules that are not common and I don't want to play by them, namely the auto-resign.

I never want to be auto-resigned when I have time left and I do not want my partner to be auto-resigned and preventing me from winning. In addition, I do not want my partner to get indications on which opening is played and the quality of moves as happens on chess.com in live games.

I signed up to chess24 but it seems they no longer offer online play.

Comment: What do you mean by auto-resign?

Comment: @Lucenaposition If you don't make a move within about 15 seconds in the first few moves, it forces you to resign. (Really annoying in 960 when you want to look at the opening position for more than a few seconds.)

Comment: On chess.com the game is aborted, not resigned.

Comment: I believe it is the same on lichess

Comment: There is no auto-resign on lichess. You have to make the first move within 30s in order for it not to be aborted. The rest is normal chess

Comment: @Hauptideal looking for 100% normal chess.

Comment: No chess site is ever going to be "100% normal" due to the basic sensibilities of how online play works.

Comment: @o17tH1H'S'k would you mind posting some examples of games getting auto-resigned?

Comment: @koedem sure. game 1: . game 2: e4. of course there were also more interesting games.

Comment: @o17tH1H'S'k I meant some link so we can try to guess what happened. Before one player played their first move is indeed what is mentioned above where the site might think the player is afk. But that can only happen on that very first move. (or it might even be the opponent clicking "abort game") In more interesting games, i.e. such that go longer than a half move that should not happen.

Answer (score 4):

The rule you refer to appears to be the forfeit resulting from when a game is ‘abandoned’ for a period of 60 seconds or more. This is necessary for the smooth running of an online site with innumerable time limited games.

However, all is not lost and there may be a way out of your percieved predicament !

You and your friend could choose a long duration of play with for example one day per move: which allows you to play no less than a move a day- allowing you to play faster than this rate at your own pace and not risk forfeit from “abandoning" a game. Alternatively, another chess online play site: the Internet chess club (icc.com) has the option to add time to your opponent’s clock if you might wish.